# Concatenate two DOS commands in a java program

Tags: java, cmd

I want to concatenate two dos commands in a java program. First I want to change directory then list the files and folders in that. So I wrote that like

```
 try
    {
      Process process = UI.this.rt.exec("cmd.exe /c cd C:\\Users & start dir");
      process.waitFor();
      InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
      while (in.read() != -1) {}
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
```

But this is not working. When I execute this in desktop it is not change the directory and display the files and folders which is in the desktop. Could you please help me to fix this problem? I'm using windows 7 machine.

Thanks

Isuru Liyanage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the commands to a batch file on the disk and execute the batch.
If you don't want to have such a batch on the disk, create it on demand and delete it after usage.
Or just use the java build-in features to list files.

EDIT
But your code works. I tried it.
It opens a dos-box an lists the directory **after changing** the directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ProcessBuilder to set the working directory of the Process you exec later.

Or, do as suggested else-thread and use the Java API for listing files in a directory, which is saner.

Answer (score 1):

While creating a process you can pass a string array of commands as below:

```
String[] command = new String[3];
                command[0] = "cmd";
                command[1] = "/c";
                command[2] = " cd c:\\Users && dir";

                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the start, it runs files in a new window. Plus as there in no cmd in the NEW command DIR won't be recognised as a command. If you must use start for some reason add cmd /c to the dir part as well.

also `dir c:\users` is all you actually need to do. No need or reason to change directory.